# Regex match up to first PRECEDING space from character

Tags: regex

I have this snippet here

```
agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; Trident/6.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko custom1=custom1 custom2=custom2 more=otherstuffi dont care about etc
```

What I want is a regex that matches up to here

```
agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

I have tried this:

```
agent=(.*?=)
```

Which gives me:

```
agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; Trident/6.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko custom1=
```

But custom1 could be fewer or more chars sometimes.. so i don't want it to be specific I want to just get everything before the space between Gecko and custom however if the browser/os isn't exact it might not be Gecko. So I feel like the best way is to use the next = (after custom1) since it will always be there.

So if I can get up to that custom1= from the agent and then only match whats before the space before custom1, that would work.

Or am I over complicating this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
agent=([^=]*)(?=\s)
```

This will match as many characters besides `=` as it can, but it will stop before the final space.

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/J3M2lr/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
agent=(.+?)\s+[^=\s]+=
```

And get you matched text in captured group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AapWPf/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `agent=`: match text `agent=`
- `(.+?)`: match 1 or more characters (lazy)
- `\s+`: match 1+ whitespace
- `[^=\s]+=`: match 1+ non-whitespace, non-`=` character followed by `=`